# Function is not found in imported file, yet still works

Tags: python, ray

The line here calls `tune.run`: https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/90b05983d616900f1ccd325bfe235cd3c38ef174/python/ray/util/sgd/torch/examples/tune_example.py#L51

However, the `tune` variable points to `ray.tune` which points to this `__init__.py` file where no `run` function is defined: 
[https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/python/ray/tune/**init**.py](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/python/ray/tune/__init__.py)

`run` is instead defined in this file: 
https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/python/ray/tune/tune.py

What is the logical reason the following steps in `tune_example.py`

```
from ray import tune
tune.run(...)
```

somehow searches https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/python/ray/tune/tune.py instead of [https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/python/ray/tune/**init**.py](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/python/ray/tune/__init__.py) for the `run` function?

Comment: The `__init__.py` file has `from ray.tune.tune import run_experiments, run` so `run` is defined there.

Comment: "However, the `tune` variable points to `ray.tune` which points to this `__init__.py` file where no run function is defined" yes it is, it's imported